# I'm New to Minecraft Servers, and I Need Help with PVP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Okay, I'm not a very good fighter of PvP in Minecraft. First of all, I'm new to servers and I don't know much about PvP since all these players have multiple tricks up their sleeves. It's not like fighting the same old monsters with an AI that programs the monsters to go straight at you. Not to mention that players can go right through you. The other problem is that I'm playing on a computer. Can someone provide me with some tips to get some kills on Minecraft while using a laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tip 1:**
Well, my first tip would be, buy a mouse. Spending even just 10 dollars on a mouse will exponentially help with PVP. Also if your computer has the capability to run fast, then let it. This helps reduce lag while in battles.

**Tip 2:**
Second off, when playing PVP, hiding and running is not bad. It can increase your chances of winning. Surprise attacks take advantage of the hiding technique. Also, players running through you can be to your advantage in some situations. If you are running away from someone, you can turn around and run right through them. This method works, but it doesn't always work on everyone. Especially those lots of PVP experience.

**Tip 3:**
Third, there is a way to get a critical strike. To get a critical strike, hit another player while falling. Also if you are using a bow, if you hold it back for longer periods of time, then it will do more damage when it hits another player. Hope this all helps!

Comment: By the way, the mob AI is much more complicated than the mobs just running straight at you. Jus sayin...

Comment: The critical strikes occur while falling, jumping works as long as you strike as gravity pulls your back, rather than during your exciting escape attempt from it.